# How to pass query parameters to a Facebook Page tab app

Tags: facebook, url, append

is it possible to add ?variable=value to the end of a facebook application url ?

for example:
facebook.com/pagename/app_abcdefghij/phppage.php?variable=value

then use a _Get to query a mysql database ?

Answer (score 3):

To pass data to a page tab app, use the app_data parameter.
The value you supply for this will be present in the `signed_request` which is POSTed to your app. Other parameters are not passed.

There's more information about this in the [page tab documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) under the header **Integrating with Facebook APIs**

Comment: Cheers, just checking the link out now

Comment: is it possible to read from the facebook url using https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here

Comment: Yes - the value of app_data is passed in the `signed_request`

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST['signed_request'])`
doesnt write anything into app body
whats wrong?
    print_r($POST['signed_request']);

Comment: It’s not $POST, but $_POST. And the signed_request is not “plain text”, you have to _decode_ it first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Yea, couldnt edit comment anymore.
Okay, so u say it wont print out anything untill i will decode it?

Comment: Tried those function from facebook docs, still nothing on the output